# Loading untrusted configurations variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am working on a bash prompt project which acts upon different states in the directory you are currently in.

What I need now is a way to load a mini configuration from the current directory, which is easily done with `. .params.conf`, except that this method is extremely unsecure, as anyone with write access to the directory you are in can create and execute command as you when you stumble upon a directory with a .params.conf file in it.

What is the best way of loading variables from a file like this?
The variables is going to be mostly in a true/false state, so I am not parsing them in any way so it can be executed.

Possible solutions:

- A loop, loading each predefined variable is a possible, but I want to keep the code in a readable fashion.
- Put the whole file in an bash array would be the best solution, but how can I populate a key/value dict in bash like this?
- If bash can source a file only loading the variables..

I dont know how the format of the params.conf file will look like yet. But I think the easiest would be one line for each param, separated by space. Like one of this on each line: `key value that can have space in it`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval` can be [very insecure](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) and can still execute malicious code. It's better to use `declare`:

```
while read varname value
do
    declare "$varname=$value"
done < .params.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

If your values do not contain quotes, it is rather easy:

```
while read varname value ; do
    eval $varname="'$value'"
done < .params.conf
```

If there are quotes inside of the variables, you have to be more careful and add some escaping.